# Is there any way to verify dynamic pop-up that does not appear everytime

Tags: jasmine, protractor

```
var name = element(by.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'We will be adding this information')]"));
        if ( browser.isElementPresent(name)) {
            try {
                element(by.xpath("//button[@class='ok-btn']")).click();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Not able to click on duplicate pop-up '+error);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Fresh');
        }
```

Above code works perfectly fine in Protractor jasmine framework, if popup appears but it fails when pop-up doesn't appear and scripts execution stops there.
Popup comes only when certain condition matches.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this using the elementFinder method isPresent() instead of the browser method.

```
const name = element(by.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'We will be adding this information')]"));

if (name.isPresent()) {
    try {
        element(by.xpath("//button[@class='ok-btn']")).click();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Not able to click on duplicate pop-up '+error);
    }
} else {
    console.log('Fresh');
}
```

Comment: Hi @DublinDev   
I have tried your code but 'element(by.xpath("//button[@class='ok-btn']")).click();' always executes.
When pop-up does not appears above code fail, same old issue.

Comment: But below solution worked for me
```
name.isPresent().then(function(result) {
            if ( result ) {
                element(by.xpath("xpath")).click();
            } else {
                console.log('Fresh');
            }
            });
```
Thanks :) @Ebru Yener